# Reference error #1065 (Application Domain) when using GetDefinitionByName

Tags: actionscript-3, dns

I have a .swf file that uses the following code:

```
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
var popUpClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(e.currentTarget.popUp) as Class;
popUpContent = new popUpClass();
}
```

However when I load that swf into another "container" swf I am getting a Reference Error #1065. I have been reading several posts on stack overflow (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480997/as3-getdefinitionbyname-error-1065-variable-class-name-is-not-defined) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752549/preloader-in-actionscript-3-reference-error-on-getdefinition)) but I am still confused as to what to do.

For example, do I change the code in my "loaded swf" to reference it's own application domain (not the domain of the container swf?) and if so, how do I do this exactly?

OR do I load the swf file and assign it it's own application domain in the code of the container? (not the code for the loaded swf?)

Also, my "e.currentTarget.popUp" just has a short name "PopUpWhateverName" should I be giving it a full package name like "com.MyLoadedSwf.Assets.PopUpWhateverName"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , full package name : getDefinitionByName("com.MyLoadedSwf.Assets.PopUpWhateverName")

but You can also try :

```
var popUpClass:Class = e.currentTarget.popUp.constructor;
popUpContent = new popUpClass();
```